# Javascript error on href getElementById when null

Tags: javascript

I have a popup that lets the user change a href if set or not. If not set, I display "optional web link" as field title. However, I'm getting a JavaScript error on the "if" line that href is null. How can I get href or test it without the error getting in the way? In this application href will be null at times so I need my script to deal with it somehow.

```
if (document.getElementById('sidebarhref-'+id).href == '') {
    var href = document.getElementById('sidebarhref-'+id).href;
} else {
    var href = 'optional web link';
}
```

Comment: document.getElementById('sidebarhref-'+id).attr("href")

Comment: @Mike no, that is incorrect.  You're thinking of jQuery, but the OP isn't using that.

Comment: @Mike — `null` doesn't have an `attr` method … and nor does an HTMLElement object. You've changed the code so instead of throwing an error when the element exists, it **always** throws an error.

Comment: oops. thanks @Pointy

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Test if the return value of getElementById is a true value before trying to access properties of it.

```
var element = document.getElementById('sidebarhref-'+id);
if (element && element.href === "") {
// etc
```

Comment: Thank you! Update as follows:

    `var element = document.getElementById('sidebarhref-'+id);

    if (element && element.href != '') {

        var href = element.href;

    } else {

        var href = 'optional web link';

    }`